# Count number of negative reviews for each month and put in array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have simple table in a DB like this:

```html
id date   feedback
0 2014–10-25  0
1 2014–10-28  1
1 2014–10-29  1
2 2014–11-14  1
3 2014–11-18  0
4 2015–01-10  2
5 2015–01-18  1
```

I'm trying to find out how i can gather the following information with PHP from my table:

1. total number of feedback results for 0, 1, 2 (0 being negative, 1 neutral, 2 postive) for each month.

So for example, Oct 2014 had 1 negative and 2 neutral reviews.

I'd like to store the results in an array.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select date_format(date, '%b %Y'), 
case feedback when 0 then 'negative' when 1 then 'neutral' when 2 then 'positive' end case, 
count(feedback) 

from your_table 

group by date_format(date, '%b %Y'), feedback
```

Use this query and in your fetch (using PDO) do this:

```
fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP)
```

Using PDO:

> $sth = $dbh->prepare("select date_format(date, '%b %Y'), 
>        case feedback when 0 then 'negative' when 1 then 'neutral' when 2 then 'positive' end case, 
>        count(feedback)");
>
> $sth->execute();    /* Group values by the first column */
>   var_dump($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP));

Answer (score 0):

Well i hope this is not an over kill! But I prepared some classes to help you handle your problem in a way that makes the code reuseable.

in the same directory i have the following files

1. constants.php
2. db.php
3. review.php

/***********constants.php*************/

```
define('USER','root');
define('HOST','localhost');
define('DBNAME','dbsupd');
define('PASS','');

define('NEGATIVE',0);
define('NEUTRAL',1);
define('POSITIVE',2);
```

/***********db.php*************/

```
require_once("constants.php");

class dbMySql
{
    protected $_connection;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->openConnection();
    }

    public function openConnection()
    {
        try
        {       
            $this->connection = new PDO('mysql:host=' .HOST.';'.'dbname='.DBNAME,USER,PASS);
        }
        catch(PDOexception $e)
        {
            $this->_connection = NULL;
            echo("error: ".$e->getMessage());
            die();
        }
    }

    public function doQueryPreReturn($queryIn, array $Params)
    {
        if (isset($this->connection))
        {
            $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($queryIn);

            $stmt->execute($Params);

            $resultSet = $stmt->fetchAll();

            return $resultSet;
        }
    }
}
```

/************************review.php***************************/

```
class Review extends dbMySql
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getReviewByType($type)
    {
        $query = "SELECT id,date,feedback FROM review where feedback = ?"; // not comfortable with the column named "date" though
        $param = array();

        $param = $this->getParamByType($type);

        $review = $this->doQueryPreReturn($query,$param);

        return $review;
    }

    public function getReviewCountByType($type)
    {
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM review where feedback = ?"; 
        $param = array();

        $param = $this->getParamByType($type);

        $review = $this->doQueryPreReturn($query,$param);

        return $review;
    }

    private function getParamByType($type)
    {
        $param = array();

        switch($type)
        {
            case NEGATIVE:
                return array(NEGATIVE);
            case NEUTRAL:
                return array(NEUTRAL);
            case POSITIVE:
                return array(POSITIVE);
        }
    }
}
```

You can now use these classes from a separate file like so

```
require_once("constants.php");
require_once("db.php");
require_once("review.php");

$reviewInst = new Review();

// get all neutral reviews
$neutralRev = $reviewInst->getReviewByType(NEGATIVE);

print_r($neutralRev);

// get count of neutral reviews 

$count = $reviewInst->getReviewCountByType(NEGATIVE);
print_r($neutralRev);
```